# Getting data back from django views.py and using ajax to display it

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

**EDITED**

I'm trying to use jquery/ajax to display data returned from a django method.

I have a html button called keywordBtn. So when it's pressed, the updateKeywordSubscribed method will be called.

however, my object is not being returned by django. Is there something wrong with my method?

If successful, the div section name "update" would display the list of words in that json list.

what i have in my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#keywordBtn").click(function(e) { 
                updateKeywordSubscribed(e, "#keywords"); 
            });
        });
        function updateKeywordSubscribed(e, keywords) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var option_form = jQuery(e.target);
            $.ajax({
                url : option_form.attr('action'),
                type : option_form.attr('method'),
                data : option_form.serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response) { alert ('sometext')})
        }
</script>
```

what i have in my views.py:

```
def keyword_subscribe(request):
    if 'keyword_input' in request.POST:
    if 'name_input' in request.POST:
        xhr = request.GET.has_key('xhr')
        response_dict = {}
            new_keyword = request.POST['keyword_input']
        username = request.POST['name_input']
        response_dict.update({'keyword_input': new_keyword, 'name_input': username})
        power_keyword = subscribe_keyword(username,keywords)
        if power_keyword:
            response_dict.update({'success':True})
        else:
            response_dict.update({'errors':{}})
            if not username:
                        response_dict['errors'].update({'name_input': 'User ID is required'})
                if not total and total is not False:
                        response_dict['errors'].update({'keyword_input': 'Keyword field is blank'})
        if xhr:
                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
            return render_to_response('r2/userprofile_list.html', response_dict)
```

Comment: i just need to understand how jquery reads that data from views.py. The rest i'll be able to fill it in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm doing something similar to what you need in my current project.

I GET this zipcode view which returns a geojson result or null

## My View:

```
def get_zipcode(request, latitude, longitude):
    # Point on a map
    point = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s)' % (longitude, latitude))

    try :
        zipcodes = Zipcode.objects.filter(mpoly__contains=point)
        return HttpResponse(zipcodes[0].mpoly.geojson, mimetype="application/json")
    except :
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(None), mimetype="application/json")
```

my mimetype is application/json not application/javascript

## My urls:

```
url(r'^collision/zipcode/(?P<latitude>(\-|)\d+\.\d+)/(?P<longitude>(\-|)\d+\.\d+)/', 'core.views.get_zipcode', name='collision-zipcode'),
```

## The JS that makes the call and handles the json result

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/collision/zipcode/' + latitude + '/' + longitude + '/',
    dataType : 'json',
    type : 'GET',
    success: function(data)
    {
        var paths = coord_to_paths(data.coordinates); 
        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
            paths : paths, 
            strokeColor : "#FF7800", 
            strokeOpacity : 1, 
            strokeWeight : 2, 
            fillColor : "#FF7800", 
            fillOpacity : 0.6
        });

        polygon.setMap(map);

        console.log("adding zipcode polygon");
    }
});
```

note that if you are doing retrieving json, if you set the dataType to 'json', you should be go to access data in your success function as a JS native.

if you need to debug what data is actually being retrieved by jquery, do a

```
console.log(data);
```

and look in your dev console w/i your browser (chrome/ff I dont know if other browsers support this)

Comment: Wow Francis, good answer, can you help me see the picture in which part in the success function is the data being passed in from views?

Comment: in my example my ajax success function takes a single param "data" which is the json response. it looks like your ajax success function calls it response. you should console.log it to see what you are getting. if i had to guess, something is wrong in your view and it is not returning good json, so you success function doesn't know what to do with it.